# I get the following error when trying to set a wallpaper

Tags: java, android

```
public HeavyLifter(Context context, Handler callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.manager = (WallpaperManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WALLPAPER_SERVICE);
    }
```

> Error: Suspicious cast to WallpaperManager for a WALLPAPER_SERVICE:
>   expected WallpaperService [ServiceCast]   this.manager =
>   (WallpaperManager)
>   context.getSystemService(Context.WALLPAPER_SERVICE);

How can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `getInstance()` method of `WallpaperManager` to get ahold of an instance.

Change the following:

```
this.manager = (WallpaperManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WALLPAPER_SERVICE);
```

To this:

```
this.manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
```