# What's the difference between WallpaperManager.getInstance() vs getSystemService(Context.WALLPAPER_SERVICE)

Tags: java, android, android-wallpaper

What's the difference between using [`WallpaperManager.getInstance(context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getInstance(android.content.Context)) and `(WallpaperManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WALLPAPER_SERVICE)`?

If I open source code for `getInstance()` method, it returns `(WallpaperManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WALLPAPER_SERVICE)`, so obviously there is no difference. But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38800216/1253279), using `getInstance()` solved OP's problem. Also, [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) suggest using `getSystemService()`.

Which approach is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

As i see it, the main difference is: due to `getInstance()` is `static` method, this instance created only once, all the subsequent times this instanсe is used. So when you call `static getInstance()`, you probably use already created instance.

Comment: A static method does not mean that it returns the same instance of the object.